# Excel Formula for duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

Could somebody kindly show me the formula I need to create the exact data I have in column C:

[image]

Any duplicate cells in column B will copy the sku from column A into column C.

Hope I have explained this ok!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have Office 365 Excel you will need a UDF.  Put this code in a Module attached to the workbook:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    If TEXTJOIN <> "" Then 
        TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim)) 
    Else
        TEXTJOIN = ""
    End IF
End Function
```

Then the following array formula will do what you want:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$11<>A2,IF($B$2:$B$11=B2,$A$2:$A$11,""),""))
```

being an array formula it will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

If you have Office 365 Excel just use the formula above as an array formula, no need for the UDF.

The UDF mimics the functionality of TEXTJOIN.

[image]